# Udacity Sunshine - App crashes after binding array adapter to listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-fragmentactivity

Using android studio 1.2, the fragment is in a separate MainActivityFragment.java file. Is there anything I need to change to get this to work? I tried to follow the repository as much as I could.

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MainActivityFregment.java

```js
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
        String[] data = {
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

        // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
        // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
        // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for `R.layout.list_item_forecast` and `R.id.list_item_forecast_textview` if you named correctly and Show `logcat` error

Answer (score 2):

Change this line in your code

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
```